# Best way to flip a CAEAGLLayer for presentation in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, avfoundation

Open GL ES coordinates are flipped on the y axis compared to iOS. Saving the data out via glreadpixels (to a video) gives me the proper transformation, but displaying in a UIView has the y axis flipped. What is the best way to flip it back for presentation?

I'm seeing three ways so far:

1) Render twice in opengl, sending the non-flipped version to glreadpixels, and a flipped version to the CAEAGLLayer (presentRenderbuffer).

2) Flip the pixels in opengl so it displays properly; once I've read them via glreadpixels, shift the bits then save that to file.

3) Flip the pixels in opengl so it displays properly; apply some type of transform on the video itself (causing it to flip at the time of playback).

I'm not sure any of these are the right path. Looking for the most performant path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best way is by using flipped vertices in opengl.

Answer (score 4):

Just apply a transform to the UIView to flip it. For example:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I'm curious about the performance of this method vs. any others. Apple seems to say that, in 4.2 and beyond, transforms on EAGLLayers is ok, while before it resulted in reduced performance. I guess I'll have to do some tests if no one else chimes in.

Comment: It certainly used to be the case that some transforms (and some types of compositing; this is why they always say to keep your OpenGL view opaque) pushed iOS into going down a slow route — including rotations by 90 degrees on the older MBX hardware. I'm not sure of the position now. I would guess that, if the current solution proves too slow, it might be smart to render to a framebuffer object, glReadPixels from that, then bind it as a texture and do a flipped draw directly in OpenGL.

Comment: I wanted to point out that this method did not work for me on an iPhone 4, but it did on a 3Gs. Does not make a bit of sense, but it's the truth.